# how can I transmit a constant to my embedded device, while the API needs a pointer?

Tags: c, embedded

Given an API like this :

`write_data(uint32_t address,uint8_t *data)`

how can I transmit a constant to my embedded device, like 0x001 ?

Comment: How does the API know how much data to copy, i.e. the number of bytes to copy from `data` ?

Comment: You want to place this constant on the data? Can't you simply copy its value to the data pointer?

Comment: @cnicuta : that's not my api. My doc suggests a single byte, passed as pointer.

Comment: This is **very ugly** so I'd **recommend not doing it** except in a pinch, throwaway code (that you have the authority to see disposed of), etc: `write_data(12345, (uint8_t *) "\xff");` If your data type is longer than a `char`, it gets even worse, as you'll have to encode the bytes **in accordance with your platform's endianness**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton As you said, your solution _could_ work, but it could also fails on some platforms, as removing the const from the pointer will not always result into a valid pointer (like a Renesas platform with 16bit RAM-pointer and 32bit const pointer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a variable and assign the constant to it. Then you pass a pointer to the variable.

Comment: @ZanLynx I believe you mean to pass a reference to the variable. In this case is important to check if the API implementation copies the data, otherwise it may reference the stack pointer that may become invalid (assuming your variable is on the stack).

Comment: @fhsilva: This depends on the API. If it uses the value to copy, as I suspect it does, then using a stack variable is fine. Because after `write_data()` returns it is no longer using the pointer and it is safe to release the memory.